# How can I add extra html tags to Syntastic plugin for Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim, tidy, syntastic

I use a CMS which uses custom tags that are parsed before everything on the page, for example. This can appear in the standard file formats for .html, .php

```
<v:img for="portfolio" />
```

and it will create an an image based on all the specifications in the backend..

also things like

```
<v:php>
// Code here is different than <?php ?> which is rendered after v:php
</v:php>
```

and

```
<v:collection for="blog">
  <h1><v:text for="title" /></h1>
</v:collection>
```

Thats it as far as format goes, there are hundreds of tags but they are either closed or self closed just like html.

I'm trying to add them to the Syntastic plugin for Macvim so I don't get unnecessary errors but this is a bit over my head :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/path/to/syntastic/syntax_checkers/html.vim`, look at line 26 `let makeprg="..."`.

You can see that there are a bunch of new HTML5 tags added to the `tidy` command, you should try to add your tags there.

See [the tidy documentation](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#docs) if there are any caveats.